# PHP: session_cookie over subdomains?

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm rather new to PHP and sessions.
I've actually never worked with them before and I'm having quite a few problems working with them with AJAX over a subdomain.

I'm on *http://www.example.com/whatever* and I'm setting the cookie with:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['password']) ) {
    $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
}
var_dump(ini_get_all('session')); //seems like it doesn't save the cookie???
```

Then I'm using jQuery (`load()`) to reload a certain part of the page. I'm loading *somefile.php* from *http://subdomain.example.com/subdomain/somefile.php*. I want to retrieve the session information inside this *somefile.php*. I'm using

```
var_dump(ini_get_all('session')); //can't find the cookie!??

if(isset($_SESSION['password']) ) {
    $user_pass = $_SESSION['password'];
    echo "Password: " . $user_pass . "<br>";
} else {
    print "can't find cookie!";
}
```

But I can't get the information! Any idea what I could have done wrong? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you check if the session cookie is properly set and returned with the subsequent request?

Answer (score 2):

If the subdomain is run on a different server then... the session simply isn't there! This is because session data is by default saved somewhere in /tmp.

If you want to share session data across multiple servers, you'll need to write your own session handler and save them, for example, in a database.
[Session_set_save_handler()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Comment: no it's on the same server. the weird thing is i think WORDPRESS is the bugger. because if i var_dump on my first example above (where i set the cookie) it isn't there either!!! ??? any ideas?

maybe wordpress won't let me set the cookie. i don't get it! i edited above.

Comment: As far as I can tell wordpress uses a custom session handler. You'll have to use it on the other script too.

Comment: is theree a way to use set_cookie() over SUBDOMAINS. does session_set_cookie_params() work for that as well?

Comment: +1 for useing database, thats the olny thing that i can think off.

Answer (score 0):

Even within the structure of the relevant RFCs getting cookies to work across sub-domians is far from trivial. Add to that the complication of the variation in different implementations by different browser suppliers - it's just not worth the hassle.

Use SSO instead. This has been discussed [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sso+php) on Stack Overflow

C.